# abas-ERP: condition throwing unexpected error

Tags: erp, abas

I have a FO-program that throws an error when it approaches this line:

```
.continue ERR1 ? F|defined(M|yhnum) & M|yhnum > 10
```

The error is

> M|yhnum: not found

Why does this happen? I thought it wouldn't happen if I checked if the variable is defined before accessing it, but it doesn't seem like it worked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is, that FO doesn't use short circuit evaluation. This means that it will always check if `M|yhnum` is bigger than 10, even if it is not defined. Obviously, this will fail if it is not defined.

From the documentation:

> This means that a Boolean expression will be completely evaluated even if the final result can already be seen from the intermediate result. This is significant in connection with defined().

Use `F|condexpr` to manually achieve short circuit evaluation

```
.continue ERR1 ? F|condexpr(F|defined(M|yhnum), M|yhnum > 10, G|false)
```